# Are there any web apps that can keep track of collections of books or movies?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a large library of books and DVDs and I would like some way to keep track of what I have and what I have loaned out to friends.

Comment: This is similar to: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/looking-for-social-media-collector-apps

Comment: Except for the "social" component of the other question

Comment: The need to keep track of loans is also unique to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [OpenDB](http://opendb.iamvegan.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). You would need to host it yourself, but it should be easy to get running on any basic Apache+PHP capable computer. GoDaddy also offers it as an installable application on their hosting plans.

Answer (score 7):

If you're comfortable using a site just for books, I've always loved [LibraryThing.com](http://LibraryThing.com). They also have a tagging mechanism that I've used to keep track of books that are loaned out - e.g. tag them "loaned out" and "loaned to X" and then you can easily look at all books in the "loaned out" tag and see who has them.

Answer (score 3):

Disclosure: I work at Ragic

You can try to build one yourself with [Ragic](http://www.ragic.com). Just create data forms like you would on Excel or other types of spreadsheets, and it becomes an online database for you to enter and search for records.

Answer (score 1):

On the books side of your question.  I'd strongly suggest [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/).

I used LibraryThing for a while but the site design is not great (a bit unintuitive) so I switched to Goodreads after it was voted top of Lifehacker's Hive Five and have been very pleased with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could find so far, [listal.com](http://listal.com) looks pretty good and allows you to manage various media types as well as record who you loaned each item to.

**Edit** : An [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/is-there-a-webapp-that-allows-barcode-scanning-with-a-webcam#answer-1394) to a [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/is-there-a-webapp-that-allows-barcode-scanning-with-a-webcam) I asked reminded that you could also use [GuruLib](http://www.gurulib.com) : a lot of very good features, although I don't like it's design.

Answer (score 0):

- [Livingsocial](http://www.livingsocial.com)
- [Google Books](http://books.google.com/)

Or maybe you can use Google Tasks with deadlines to remind yourself who owes you what, when. I personally find that inputting books/media is a hassle on these type of sites.

Answer (score 0):

**[Flickchart](http://www.flickchart.com)** keeps track of the movies you've seen and the movies you *haven't* seen by way of giving you movie matchups to rank your taste in movies over time. After ranking films for a while. it will also tell you exactly how many films you've seen in your lifetime, and how much of your life you've spent watching movies.

Answer (score 0):

**[Listal.com](http://www.listal.com/)**

> Organize your Movie/TV, Music, Game or Book collections.
>
> List your owned, watched, read or played items and share with friends.

Answer (score 0):

You should really give a chance to [Moviez.4pu](http://www.moviez.4pu.com) . It's very statistical. You can see which of the IMDB top 250 you own/saw (The list is updated weekly). Also stuff like what's your favorite horror movie, who is your favorite actor and much much more.

Answer (score 0):

I use [iheartmovies](http://www.iheartmovies.com/) for movies (also tracks loans) and [anobii](http://www.anobii.com/) for books.

I've been thinking a lot of time about creating a db from myself, which could track exactly what I want, but these two platforms behave almost as I wanted, so there is no need to reinvent the fire...

Answer (score -1):

[BillMonk](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.billmonk.com%2F&ei=d-A0TOqbLsP48AbTl_zICw&usg=AFQjCNHLWo3vl-TLRPYskc3Sp8-bwinB6Q) does exactly that. It also allows you to split bills with your friends and keeps track of everything.

Comment: Completely unrelated answer

Comment: @George, care to explain? BillMonk helps keep track of collections of DVDs, Books and whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

For books… http://readernaut.com/