# Is there a webapp that allows barcode scanning with a webcam?

Tags: flash, barcode

Some time ago, I used a web app to catalog my book collection, and it had that really nifty little flash thing that would use your webcam to scan a barcode, extract the ISBN from that and run an amazon search on that.

Has anybody seen something like that, or can help me remember which collection manager web app had this feature ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Guru Lib](http://www.gurulib.com/_scripts/barcode/gurulib_barcode.html) seems to have a barcode scanner, I've never tried it though ([home page](http://www.gurulib.com/)).

There is an [instruction](http://gurulib.wordpress.com/2007/12/28/a-flash-based-webcam-barcode-reader/) in their blog.

Comment: Yes, that was the one! Thank you neo

Comment: +1 this looks hot !! my library is a mess right now ! *Summer Project*

Comment: +1! I wish the Add button didn't redirect to the Guru Lib website though.

Comment: The GuruLib page now seems to redirect to holding pages filled with ads.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [BarcodePedia](http://en.barcodepedia.com/) will scan books with a flash app and show their details. As they're *"down for maintenance"* right now, I can't tell whether or not it can run an Amazon search, but it shouldn't be too hard to run a cursory search on the ISBN that it displays.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use http://www.tineye.com.

It is not dedicated for a book or barcode search but if you search for a book image, search results from amazon are displayed too.